# INVALID_WSDL error when calling SOAP service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm programming a SOAP client for an existing soap web service. 
I'm using Wildfly8.2 as a server where the client is and JbossWS, JAX-WS

I generated the classes needed to call the service via eclispe with the NEW-> Web service client wizzard

When I call the service I got the error INVALID_WSDL ... the stack trace is on the bottom.

The actual problematic service call is the call to "addService" method of the web service.

This is the code that I use to call the service:

```
SOAP service1 = new SOAP();
WorkflowEditor workflowEditor = service1.getSOAPPort();

AddService parameters = new AddService();
parameters.setLogicalURI(logicalUri);
parameters.setServiceDescription(serviceDescription);
parameters.setServiceType(servicetype.getName());
Specialties specialities = new Specialties();
specialities.getSpecialty().add("aaaa");
parameters.setSpecialties(specialities);
parameters.setWsdlLocation(wsdlLocation);
parameters.setWsdlServiceName(wsdlServiceName);
parameters.setSessionToken(currentUser.getKeystoneSessionToken());
workflowEditor.addService(parameters);
```

the generated java class for the parameters in the soap call:

```
package si.arctur.services.workflowEditor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

})
@XmlRootElement(name = "addService")
public class AddService {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String sessionToken;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String wsdlLocation;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String wsdlServiceName;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String logicalURI;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String serviceType;
    protected AddService.Specialties specialties;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String serviceDescription;


    public String getSessionToken() {
        return sessionToken;
    }


    public void setSessionToken(String value) {
        this.sessionToken = value;
    }


    public String getWsdlLocation() {
        return wsdlLocation;
    }


    public void setWsdlLocation(String value) {
        this.wsdlLocation = value;
    }


    public String getWsdlServiceName() {
        return wsdlServiceName;
    }


    public void setWsdlServiceName(String value) {
        this.wsdlServiceName = value;
    }


    public String getLogicalURI() {
        return logicalURI;
    }


    public void setLogicalURI(String value) {
        this.logicalURI = value;
    }


    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }


    public void setServiceType(String value) {
        this.serviceType = value;
    }


    public AddService.Specialties getSpecialties() {
        return specialties;
    }


    public void setSpecialties(AddService.Specialties value) {
        this.specialties = value;
    }

    public String getServiceDescription() {
        return serviceDescription;
    }


    public void setServiceDescription(String value) {
        this.serviceDescription = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "specialty"
    })
    public static class Specialties {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected List<String> specialty;


        public List<String> getSpecialty() {
            if (specialty == null) {
                specialty = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            return this.specialty;
        }

    }

}
```

This is the wsdl copied from the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="WorkflowEditor" targetNamespace="*****************" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wfe="*****************" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="*****************">
      <xsd:element name="addService">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="wsdlLocation" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="wsdlServiceName" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="logicalURI" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="serviceType" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="specialties">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="specialty" type="xsd:string">
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="serviceDescription" type="xsd:string">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="serviceTitle" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="addServiceResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="removeService">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="serviceURI" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="removeServiceResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="addUserToService">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="serviceURI" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="addUserToServiceResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="removeUserFromService">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="serviceURI" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="removeUserFromServiceResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="addWorkflow">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="workflowDescription_base64" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="addWorkflowResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="removeWorkflow">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="workflowURI" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="removeWorkflowResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="replaceWorkflow">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="workflowDescription_base64" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="replaceWorkflowResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getWorkflowDescription">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="workflowURI" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getWorkflowDescriptionResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="workflowDescription_base64" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getWorkflows">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getWorkflowsResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="workflows">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="workflow" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServices">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServicesResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="services">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="service" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServiceIOs">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="serviceURI" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServiceIOsResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="serviceIOs">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="serviceIO" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServiceInfo">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="serviceURI" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServiceInfoResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="wsdlLink" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServicesInfo">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="sessionToken" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="getServicesInfoResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="success" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                <xsd:element name="services">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="service">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serviceURI" type="xsd:string">
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="serviceDescription" type="xsd:string">
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serviceWSDL" type="xsd:string">
                                            </xsd:element>
                                            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="serviceTitle" type="xsd:string">
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="removeWorkflowRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:removeWorkflow">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addWorkflowRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:addWorkflow">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeUserFromServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:removeUserFromService">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:removeService">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServicesRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServices">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeUserFromServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:removeUserFromServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="replaceWorkflowRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:replaceWorkflow">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServicesInfoRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServicesInfo">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getWorkflowDescriptionRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getWorkflowDescription">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServicesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServicesResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServiceIOsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServiceIOsResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServiceInfoResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServiceInfoResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addUserToServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:addUserToServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeWorkflowResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:removeWorkflowResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getWorkflowDescriptionResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getWorkflowDescriptionResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServiceInfoRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServiceInfo">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getWorkflowsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getWorkflowsResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServiceIOsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServiceIOs">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="replaceWorkflowResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:replaceWorkflowResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:addServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addUserToServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:addUserToService">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:removeServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getServicesInfoResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getServicesInfoResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addWorkflowResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:addWorkflowResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getWorkflowsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:getWorkflows">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="wfe:addService">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WorkflowEditor">
    <wsdl:operation name="addService">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:addServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:addServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeService">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:removeServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:removeServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addUserToService">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:addUserToServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:addUserToServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeUserFromService">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:removeUserFromServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:removeUserFromServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addWorkflow">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:addWorkflowRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:addWorkflowResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeWorkflow">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:removeWorkflowRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:removeWorkflowResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="replaceWorkflow">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:replaceWorkflowRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:replaceWorkflowResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getWorkflowDescription">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:getWorkflowDescriptionRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:getWorkflowDescriptionResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getWorkflows">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:getWorkflowsRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:getWorkflowsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServices">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:getServicesRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:getServicesResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServiceIOs">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:getServiceIOsRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:getServiceIOsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServiceInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:getServiceInfoRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:getServiceInfoResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServicesInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="wfe:getServicesInfoRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="wfe:getServicesInfoResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WorkflowEditorSOAP" type="wfe:WorkflowEditor">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="addService">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************addService"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeService">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************removeService"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addUserToService">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************addUserToService"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeUserFromService">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************removeUserFromService"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addWorkflow">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************addWorkflow"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeWorkflow">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************removeWorkflow"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="replaceWorkflow">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************replaceWorkflow"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getWorkflowDescription">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************getWorkflowDescription"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getWorkflows">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************getWorkflows"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServices">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************getServices"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServiceIOs">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************getServiceIOs"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServiceInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************getServiceInfo"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getServicesInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="*****************getServicesInfo"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SOAP">
    <wsdl:port name="SOAPPort" binding="wfe:WorkflowEditorSOAP">
      <soap:address location="*******************************"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The stack trace error:

```
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /html): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.checkElementName(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.createClientSideAxisService(AxisService.java:2317)
... 29 more
```

Comment: Did you generate your web service client with axis or axis2? And does your server has axis or axis2?

Comment: I have generated it with Eclipse Kepler, I left the default settings, it looks like that uses JbossWS and not axis ...

Comment: I can say that it is using axis2 from the stacktrace **org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService** maybe you schould include axis dependent jars in your webapp...

Comment: But other methods of the same web service are working ok ... for example the method "getWorkflows" works ok

Comment: `XmlType` annotation is empty in your generated class. I don't know how it may have been generated, but you should try alternatively a)removing it completely, b)pass the obvious data (both the name 'addService' and the names of the properties to the `propOrder`).

Comment: In `Specialties` class the name is also empty. Try removing the empty `name` attribute and leave the `propOrder` as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to create your service in this way:

```
SOAP service1 = new SOAP(new URL(yourURL));
```

But as `yourURL` pass value with `?wsdl` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is malformed...

Line 1: There are 2 spaces before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

It could be because of the way you are downloading/saving the wsdl using a browser. I discovered this when trying to load your wsdl into SoapUI, it rejected it. then I used an [online xml validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) to find what line was malformed.

Comment: this is just a mistake I made when posting the question, I forgot to delete the spaces.

Comment: A few things you could check are (1) Does the soap address location match your actual server address/version? and (2) The wsdl must be case sensitive, do all of your definitions match the correct case?

Answer (score 0):

`XmlType` annotation is incomplete for both `AddService` and `Specialties` classes.

Try to add the obvious `name` of each type, plus the obvious properties order in `propOrder`, or alternatively remove them completely if they are irrelevant.